# How to change the postgres database user role password from 'admin' to 'mypassword'?

Tags: postgresql, odoo, odoo-10

I was trying to change PostgreSQL database user role password from 'admin' to 'mypassword' in odoo-10. I've tried `ALTER ROLE "odoo" WITH PASSWORD 'mypassword';` in postgres and restarted **postgresql service**.

But it is not working. 
When i start **odoo server** again it shows error like **FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "odoo"** and It is working fine if I change this password back to 'admin'. I've tried of making corresponding changes in both "**/etc/odoo.cof**" and "**/odoo/tools/config.py**" and it does'nt solve my issue too.

Is there anything else that i missed to try ? Hope you'll help me to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Did you change the db_password in your conf file, right? I am asking because admin is default master odoo password, not db password.

Comment: Do you wanna hack the admin user?

Comment: No. I'm trying to prevent hacking @AxelMendoza

Comment: @TadeuszKarpinski ya. I tried that too.

Comment: Yea. So when you change password in psql without changing password in conf file, does it work?

Answer (score 6):

**Try this:**

```
$sudo -u postgres psql database_name

$ALTER USER postgres with encrypted password 'ur password';
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this single line:

```
sudo -u postgres psql -c "ALTER USER <user> WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD '<password>';"
```

replace `<user>` and `<password>` with corresponding data.